# Solving $8n^2 < 64n\log n$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm analysing algorithms and trying to find out for which values of n does one algorithm out perform the other and I have come up with that equation. Unfortunately my maths ability is now embarrassingly bad as I have not done real maths in a long time...

I have done this:

$$8n^2 < 64n\log n$$

$$8n < 64\log n$$

$$8n/64 < \log n$$

$$n/8 < \log n$$

$$e^{n/8} < e^{\log n}$$

$$e^{n/8} < n$$

And now I'm stuck with that variable exponent.

Comment: @Jamal Moir Check if the edit is okay.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Ah, thanks for doing that!

Comment: The equation $\frac{e^n}{8} = n$ is transcendental and has no closed for equation, but some quick manual checking shows that the equality holds for $n \geq 27$ but not $n \leq 26$. One could formalize this a bit, for example, using Newton's method.

Comment: You can use Wolframalpha to solve this - it comes up with $25$ integer solutions $2\le n\le26$ - see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+over+integers+e%5E%28x%2F8%29+%3C+x)

Comment: @Travis oh I see thank you. I was hoping I could whittle it down to a nice inequality, but I guess I can't!

Comment: @Mufasa Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. This is the best one can do without resorting to special functions; the relevant one here is the *Lambert-W function*, but it's really nothing more than a function that gives a name to solutions of the sort of inequality at hand, so one doesn't gain much in this situation from appealing to it.